# How to send back two objects in res.send() in an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have an get API like this

```
router.get('/exist', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { user: { _id: userId } } = req;
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const profile = await Profile.findById(user.profile, 'role admin');
    const admin = await Admin.findOne({ _id: profile.admin })
    res.send(admin.role,profile);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

In `admin` there is only one field one want to send back called role. That's why in res.send() I have written `admin.role`.

So essentially I want send back these two fields together `admin.role` and `profile`.

Till now I have tried merge with

```
Object.assign(profile,admin)
```

&

```
{...profile,...admin}
```

Both of these didn't work.

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you pass `{...profile,...admin}` to `res.send()`, like `res.send({...profile,...admin})`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create new object like

```
 res.send({'Role':admin.role,'profile': profile});
```